# Converting audio call to video call and everyone’s call convert to video call

Tags: flutter, dart, callkit, videocall, flutter-webrtc

If there are 3 or more person in a single group call and one of the user request to switch audio call into video call and only one other user accept the request then it should only convert call for that particular user not for every user. But in current scenario it converts for all the users.

Anyone have soln regarding this issue?